# Where to find ‘Spell Id’ list in Riot API?

Tags: python, python-3.8, riot-games-api

I am working with Python and Riot APIs, and I have a problem.

When I get match data with matchId, I get json for result. Then inside participants, I get spell data like this:

```
”spell1Id”: 14, 
“spell2Id”: 4,
...
```

But I can’t find list or dictionary of spell id. It is not in even [here](http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.3.1/data/en_US/summoner.json).

Am I missing something simple? Does anybody know where to find these spell ids with number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually missing something simple.It is in the link you pasted It's just called "key".